# Fragments Layout in Two by Two Grid

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, fragment

I'm trying to take four fragments and lay them out in equal in proportions in the top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right of the screen. I am admittedly lost. Here's my attempt at a programmatic layout:

```
// instantiated fragments this way for viewpager in phone version:
    fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, LevelsFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, KBFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, WaveFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, EnvFragment.class.getName()));

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.linear_layout, fragments.get(2));
    ft.add(R.id.linear_layout, fragments.get(3));
    ft.add(R.id.linear_layout, fragments.get(1));
    ft.add(R.id.linear_layout, fragments.get(0));     
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

And the basic xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

This just fills the screen with the first fragment.  I would prefer a programmatic solution such that fragments can be replaced later.

Edit: I should mention that I would like something that is flexible enough for 2 fragments on top and 1 on bottom in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to my previous comment, here's how you could use Relative Layout and an invisible anchor view set in the center to avoid nested layout weights.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/anchor" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/anchor" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/anchor" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/anchor" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add the fragments as before:

```
ft.add(R.id.top_left, fragments.get(2));
ft.add(R.id.top_right, fragments.get(3));
ft.add(R.id.bottom_left, fragments.get(1));
ft.add(R.id.bottom_right, fragments.get(0));
```

Comment: This not only works, but clears up a strange issue with a fragment layout

Comment: One of the views was pushing together and overlapping various widgets for no apparent reason. I was trying to sort that out when I tried your version.

Answer (score 0):

After more attempts, this works:

```
    ft.add(R.id.top_left, fragments.get(2));
    ft.add(R.id.top_right, fragments.get(3));
    ft.add(R.id.bottom_left, fragments.get(1));
    ft.add(R.id.bottom_right, fragments.get(0));
```

With this xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/top_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/top_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"      
        android:id="@+id/bottom_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am still open to a better answer as nester layout_weight makes eclipse angry.

Comment: This is exactly what I was about to suggest. As for the nested layout weights, you could try using TableLayout or GridLayout instead. Or use a RelativeLayout as the root, place an empty View object in the very center and use it as an anchor to fix the sizes of the four child fragment containers.

Comment: If you wanted to demonstrate the relativelayout version, I'd be happy to mark that correct (assuming it works :P ).